# Angular material 2 md-card width

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I'm having an issue with the md-card component

```
        <md-card>
            <img height="200" width="200" md-card-image src="/resources/{{odd?.image?.path}}" />
            <md-card-content>
                <button md-button>{{odd?.object?.name}}</button>
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
```

I have this code, it creates a card with an image inside and some text under the image.
I want the image to be of size 200x200 and i want the card to wrap the image completely but instead, the opposite happens, the card fills the entire width of the page and as a result, the image stretches to the size of the card

[image]

If i remove the md-card-image attribute from the img tag, it shows the image in 200x200 but the md-card is still stretched.

[image]

How can i maintain the size that i want for the image and make the md-card wrap around it?

Comment: if im correct, you need to set width for the md-card, source https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples

Comment: I'm so dumb (－‸ლ) i tried setting the width md-card but i was using the width attribute. I now created a css class for the md-card and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `css` for the sizing of your `md-card`

Source: [Here](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples)

> **PS**: its better to use `box-sizing: border-box;` so you can get the exact width...